How to contribute to Numpy
I've written a Python code to improve a Numpy function, see the code below. In this case: it determines the unique values and counts of an array, just like np.unique() is already doing, but in vectorized way, such that multiple arrays (matrix or higher dimensions) can be in the input at once, speeding up computation.
What I would like to know is the following:

How can I contribute a function like this to Numpy?
In what way should the code be altered to be properly implemented?
Where in Numpy's project could this function be implemented?

The code:
import numpy as np

def unique(array):
    
    values = np.unique(array)
    new_array = np.tile(array, (len(values), *np.ones(array.ndim, dtype=int)))
    counts = np.sum(new_array.T == values, axis=0)
    counts = np.moveaxis(counts.T, 0, -1)
    
    return values, counts

Example use:
array = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [1,2,2],
                  [3,3,3]])

unique(array)

Returns:
(array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]]))


np.unique can already return indices and counts, and i doubt you can outperform it with pure python. if you're interested in numpy development you should start with this page: https://numpy.org/contribute/

As with any opensource project, I would start by explain your matter in a Github Issue.
